# PHP 5.6 PDO sqlsrv CharacterSet

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, encoding, sqlsrv

I want to get data from a sql server within PHP 5.6 with PDO and sqlsrv (native and pdo extension included).
But with PDO im getting the data in a wrong encoding.

Database Collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS

---

Native:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"TestDatabase", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pwd", "CharacterSet"  => 'UTF-8');       
$conn = sqlsrv_connect("TestServer", $connectionInfo);
```

Result (with a simple sqlsrv_query):
**AeÖö**

---

PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=TestServer;Database=TestDatabase", "user", "pwd");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE id = 356");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

print_r($data);
```

Result: AeÃ–Ã¶

---

Is there an attribute or something for PDO that i can get the data in utf-8?
With the native extension it works perfectly.

### Update

I've found the solution.

For PDO this worked for me:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=TestServer;Database=TestDatabase", "user", "pwd");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM); //Important!!!

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE id = 356");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

print_r($data);
```